# Gmail labs: Can you create custom shortcuts involving Ctrl + or Alt +?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm moving from Outlook to Gmail (in Google Apps) and am setting things up in it to make it as powerful as possible in being my daily driver... (like the message pane).

I want to set up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for "Reply", and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for "Mark as unread". And probably many other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ ones therafter. But can't see a way to do it.

Have they added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> to user-creatable keyboard shortcuts or are we currently stuck only with making <kbd>Shift</kbd> ones? (I see that's smart, just give a capital letter and that's a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ shortcut.)

Answer (score 2):

I would expect not, because that'll interfere with the browser's keyboard shortcuts.

Looking at the Custom Keyboard Shortcuts lab, I don't see any way to use any sort of control key.

You could probably fake something up by using key combinations. Much the same as the standard keyboard shortcuts use <kbd>g</kbd> (for "go") then some other key for the actual action you take.

Comment: Uh I don't think so. They already have Ctrl+S (see the full list by typing "?"), which anywhere in a web browser window would bring up the browser's save page dialog. so they certainly CAN add any Ctrl + shortcut that they want. So back to my question, I wonder if they already do allow it and there's a way to short-hand specify the Ctrl key. Anyone know???

your idea sounds interesting but 1. i don't think you can have key1 + key2, just key1 THEN key2 - not the same and annoying to teach urself. plus the whole idea of shortcuts is to use the SAME ones system-wide, in ALL programs. if possible.

Comment: _They_ may be able to do it, but _you_ can't do it with the custom keyboard shortcuts. At least not as they're currently implemented.